# C# : Creating Nested dictionary using for loop

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have declared 2 dictionaries as below  for collecting number of annotations in each page of a PDF.

```
 Dictionary<string, int> tempDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
 Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>> masterDict = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>>();
```

The output am looking for is such that the tempdict will hold the annotation name as 'Key' and annotation-index as 'Value' and masterDict will hold pagenumber as 'Key' and tempDict as the 'Value'

Below is what I tried :

```
pDDoc = (CAcroPDDoc)avDoc.GetPDDoc();
int numPages = pDDoc.GetNumPages(); //Gets total number of pages in the PDF
            
for (int i = 0; i < numPages; i++)
    {
    pDPage = (CAcroPDPage)pDDoc.AcquirePage(i); //Gets the page object corresponding to pagenumber
    long y = pDPage.GetNumAnnots(); //Gets the number of annots in the acquired page
    
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
         pDAnnot = (CAcroPDAnnot)pDPage.GetAnnot(j); //Gets annot object at the 'j' index position
         string name = pDAnnot.GetTitle();
         tempDict.Add(name , j); // Name, index as Key,value
        }
    masterDict.Add(i, tempDict); // Pagenum, tempDict as Key,Value
    }
```

The above code works, but it is not the result I was expecting .If there are 10 annotations in a PDF having 2 pages, Page1 having 6 annots and Page2 having 4 annots, masterDict will look like this :

```
{[0,Count = 10]}
{[1,COunt = 10]}
```

What I want is it to look like this:

```
{[0,Count = 6]}
{[1,Count = 4]}
```

How can I achieve this ? Is Add() method the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only creating one instance of `tempDict`. You need to create a new one each loop.

Try this:

```
pDDoc = (CAcroPDDoc)avDoc.GetPDDoc();
int numPages = pDDoc.GetNumPages(); //Gets total number of pages in the PDF

for (int i = 0; i < numPages; i++)
{
    pDPage = (CAcroPDPage)pDDoc.AcquirePage(i); //Gets the page object corresponding to pagenumber
    long y = pDPage.GetNumAnnots(); //Gets the number of annots in the acquired page
    var tempDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {
        pDAnnot = (CAcroPDAnnot)pDPage.GetAnnot(j); //Gets annot object at the 'j' index position
        string name = pDAnnot.GetTitle();
        tempDict.Add(name, j); // Name, index as Key,value
    }
    masterDict.Add(i, tempDict); // Pagenum, tempDict as Key,Value
}
```